# View list of only current user objects, Django REST

Tags: python, django

I have 2 views: /notes/ and /notes//
In note model in `models.py` I have owner variable, that stores owner's login. 
Because I want to have many users, I don't want them to see other's notes, so I created the permission:

```
class IsOwner(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        return obj.owner == request.user
```

I set this permission to `NotesList(generics.ListCreateAPIView)` and `NotesDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView)`. Now user can't view other's notes if he will go to `/notes/<pk>/`, but in `/notes/` he can view the full list anyway.
So, how can I change it? I want to see in notes list only my notes. 
I think the right way is to filter `queryset = Snippet.objects.all().filter(owner=...)` but can't think right away.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are correct, you need to override the queryset in the list view. But you can't do that in the `queryset` attribute itself, because that is executed at process startup whereas you need access to data that is only available at request time. So you need to define the `get_queryset` method in that view:

```
def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
     return Snippet.objects.all().filter(owner=self.request.user)
```