# Django - how to restrict DeleteView to object owner

Tags: python, django, view

I'm trying to implement a DeleteView and prevent the model from being deleted if the user is not the owner. I'm sure it's a pretty trivial task but i can't manage to find a clear answer. So far I can see my view but currently everyone can delete the object.

Here is my code :

views.py :

```
@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class RestaurantDeleteView(DeleteView):
    model = Restaurant
    template_name = 'restaurant/delete_form.html'
    success_url = '/'
```

models.py :

```
class Restaurant(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField()
    capacity = models.IntegerField(default=0)

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [View list of only current user objects, Django REST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43496708/view-list-of-only-current-user-objects-django-rest)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42695008/how-to-restrict-access-to-objects-using-detailview-class

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the best way, but it illustrates the point.

In your `views.py`, you can access `self.get_object()` to get the model instance in reference, and then check to see if `instance.owner == self.request.user`. Look at the source code and try to remain faithful as much possible to the original. All you need is a conditional check.

Something like this:

```
@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class FooDeleteView(DeleteView):
    model = Foo
    success_url = reverse_lazy('index')

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        if self.object.owner != self.request.user:
            return redirect(self.success_url)
        return super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

If you are curious and would like to know more, you can `import pdb` and place `pdb.set_trace()` on the first line of the method, and explore what `self` is and what methods is available to it. You can do this by callin `dir(self)` once you inside the method call. You'd be surprised with the amount of things you'd discover.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `UserPassesTestMixin` to achieve this.

```py
class RestaurantDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, DeleteView):
    model = Restaurant
    template_name = 'restaurant/delete_form.html'
    success_url = '/'
    
    def test_func(self):
        restaurant = self.get_object()
        return restaurant.owner == self.request.user
```